# Bulma grids - 2x2 on mobile, 1x4 on tablet and up

Tags: css, bulma

How can I make a grid that is 1x4 on tablet and up, but 2x2 on mobile?

```
<div class="columns is-mobile" data-v-15d98976="">
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
</div>
```

However, it won't work on mobile. The two last columns are simply hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add `is-multiline` to the columns container, like so:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline" data-v-15d98976="">
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
    <div class="column is-6-mobile is-3-tablet" data-v-15d98976=""></div>
</div>
```